# Viewing and managing socket usage in Python

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I am trying to create a utility using Python (3) that, among other things, needs to look at and manage socket usage ON WINDOWS (no, I really don't care if it works on other OS's).

**Looking at socket usage:** To be clear, I don't want to create a socket or bind to an existing one, I want to be able to get a full list of what sockets are open and what programs have opened them. If you're not sure about what I mean, take a look at [TCPView](http://download.cnet.com/TCPView/3000-2094_4-10796077.html), which does exactly what I'm talking about.

**Managing socket usage:** Basically, I want to be able to stop programs from connecting from the internet, if necessary. I would assume that the easiest way to do this is to use `os.system()` to add a new rule to the Windows Firewall, but as that doesn't seem too elegant I'm open to suggestions.

As that's obviously not all the utility will do, I would prefer a library/module of some sort over a 3rd-party program.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the command "netstat -nabo" to get the list of all active connections & parse the output to get the source, destination, process name & ID. There is no straight forward method to get the active connections in python. You can also get the same information from python invoking iphlpapi. To block or allow  a connection windows has command line to add/remove rule from windows firewall.

Comment: The problem with using the command line to get output is, as far as I know, you have to write to a text file with the `>` operator in cmd, and then parse the file with python. Ugh. Is there a workaround or will I just have to deal with that?